# Draw line in canvas with another dashed line next to it

Tags: java, android, canvas

For an app I am working on I am drawing a line on a canvas using given coordinates. The problem is that I need to draw a dashed line next to it. Since the coordinates are coming from the API I only can use those coordinates for the dashed line. Is there any way to accomplish this? I really can't figure it out.

What I want:
[image]

The way I draw my current line:

```
Path line = new Path();
boolean first = true;
for (CircleArea circle : mCircles) {

    canv.drawCircle(circle.getDrawX(), circle.getDrawY(), mCircleRadius, mCirclePaint);
    if(!first) {
        line.lineTo(circle.getDrawX(), circle.getDrawY());
    } else {
        line.moveTo(circle.getDrawX(), circle.getDrawY());
    }

    first = false;
}
canv.drawPath(line, mLinePaint);
```

Sample coordinates:

- 50,50
- 75,75
- 100,75
- 150,10
- 170,10
- 170,75
- 160,75

Comment: Can you provide a sample list of coordinates you get from the server?

Comment: Added the sample coordinates, with these coordinates, the max x and y of the canvas are 200,100.

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet can be used to draw a dash path

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {20,20}, 0));
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
canvas.drawPath(line, paint);
```

Comment: This only draws a dashed line. I need to draw a normal line and a dashed line next to it.

Comment: You need to draw this two line separately and need to calculate the path coordinate for dash line from the solid path's coordinate.

Comment: The 'calculate the path coordinate for dash line' part is the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following, considering that the dashed line would be drawn above the main line at the start and continue like that:

1. If only x is changing, then the line is moving horizontally, you need only to add the distance value to the x coordinate of your dashed line
2. If only y is changing, then the line is moving virtically, you need only to add the distance value to the y coordinate of your dashed line
3. If x is positive and both x and y are changing, then you need only to add on y
4. If x is negative and both x and y are changing, then you need only to subtract from y ... etc

This way you will keep track of your original line, always doing the operations keeping in mind the last values of the coordinates and comparing them with the new ones.

Comment: Won't this give a problem when the angle of the line is less than 90 degrees? And how would you know from what point to start?

Comment: The points 3 and 4 will tackle this, you need to try and see where to change, I just gave you a start

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        Paint p1 = new Paint();
        p1.setARGB(255,0,0,0);
        p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        p1.setStrokeWidth(10);
        canvas.drawLine(0,50,500,550,p1);
        p1.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {20,20},0));
        canvas.drawLine(0,0,500,500,p1);
```

Above code is an example to create line over dotted line if x and y both are changing. Combining it with GingerHead's logic, you will get you desired path. Just loop above code and add GingerHead's logic